# AuthorizeAttribute with JWT Token- Authentication in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I implemented a JWT Bearer Token- Authentication in my Web-API that runs with .net core 2.0.
Now I created another Website that speaks with my Web-API. Retrieving the token works, I'm adding it into cookies, when I'm debugging I can see my cookie (name is "identity") with the correct value.

In the projects template there is the controller `HomeController` with the actions. I'm using the action `Contact` for my purposes and annotate it with the `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

Now I'm navigating (as an anonymous user) to `/home/contact` - perfect: it redirects me to `/home/login` where I need to login.

When I'm trying to login I get following error-message:

> No IAuthenticationSignInHandler is configured to handle sign in for the scheme: Bearer

I guess the token configuration is wrong- I guess there are a few more things I'm doing wrong here.

First, here is my Startup.cs (I didn't delete anything since there are dependencies on the order):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mysupersecret_secretkey!123")),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "ExampleIssuer",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "ExampleAudience",
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            SaveSigninToken = true
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                JwtSecurityToken accessToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
                if (accessToken != null)
                {
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = context.Result.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    identity?.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken.RawData));
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
     })
    .AddCookie(
           o =>
           {
               o.Cookie.Name = "beareridentity";
               o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login/");
               o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Login/");
           });

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ISession), serviceProvider =>
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        return httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseSession();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();


    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

and here is my login-action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginData data)
{
    var loginresult = (await _accountService.GetLoginToken(data.Username, data.Password));

    if (!loginresult.Success)
        return RedirectToAction("Login");

    Response.Cookies.Append("identity", loginresult.Token, new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.Add

    int id = await _getIdFromToken(loginresult);

    ApplicationUser user;
    await _signin(user = await _accountService.GetUserAsync(id));
    _session.SetData("actualuser", user);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private async Task _signin(ApplicationUser c)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, c.Phone??""),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, c.UserName)
    };
    var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
    ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

    try
    {
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            userPrincipal,
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now
                });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a read of this: [JWT Token Authentication with Cookies in ASP.NET Core](https://amanagrawal.blog/2017/09/18/jwt-token-authentication-with-cookies-in-asp-net-core/)? I have not tried it but it looks like that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @FrankFajardo thanks for this link. I implemented it into my application  and it works for now. AYCS there is only dummy-data, so I need to switch now that dummy data to productive data (that comes from my service/api).

Comment: so I assume that answered your question. What does AYCS mean?

Comment: In a way it answered my question yes. I didn't solve it yet but the link helped, yes. 'As you can see' :D

Comment: @FrankFajardo with your help (your link) I finally got it - thank you! You mind posting it in a short answer? (Creating that cookie and the login-method were the problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog post on how you can use cookies as a delivery mechanism for your JWTs on ASP.NET Core 2.0, which is what you are trying to do:
[JWT Token Authentication with Cookies in ASP.NET Core](https://amanagrawal.blog/2017/09/18/jwt-token-authentication-with-cookies-in-asp-net-core/)

I have not tried it, but it could guide you on understanding where you could be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The default scheme doesn't match any handler (in this case the cookie). If you can, try fitting this into your code (this might be .net core 2 specific):

```
services.AddAuthentication("YourSchemeNameHere")
.AddCookie("YourSchemeNameHere", options => 
{
    ...
});
```

If that doesn't work, change the AuthenticationScheme property in the options of the cookie to match the DefaultAuthenticateScheme in the authentication options.

Comment: Still same error when login (and I guess I need the `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as scheme because I'm using JWT). Plus, when I set `AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` and I navigate to `Home/Contact` I get a white page without any content. (Debugmode set breakpoint in the action-method but it never hits it)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Please check the Web.config and check if you have a node like  or check if there is a node for authentication, maybe this cause that, or maybe the configuration is not correct.

I am developing a mvc 5 app and my web config is like this

```
  <modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
   type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, 
   Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
   </modules>
<authentication mode="None" />
```

I am using the pre built asp.net authentication modules with their db